# Website Times Out In The UK

Tags: domain-name-system, website, timeout, domain-name, cloudflare

My site is unavailable intermittently. Unfortunately the server suffered a melt down and my host had to restore me to another server from an antiquated backup. They sorted out the DNS to point to the new location and I had an agonizing 24hrs of total unavailability.

Now, when logging in to various remote locations, this is what I experience...

- Australia - Intermittent availability with regular time-outs
- US - Regular availability with occasional time outs
- UK - Almost always timing out with occasional availability

My web host insists it's a DNS propagation thing. But I think they have messed something up. Either with the restore, DNS config or perhaps something in their security on the new server (e.g. DDOS protection... which has impeded my site's performance before, in fact that was why I was moved to the server that broke... security settings were messing with some outbound services).

I get about one reply a day from the host, and I'm at my wits end with a broken site and it's been more than 48hrs. Some pointers would be great. So at least I can try to do their job for them.

The site is [www.budgiecollective.com](http://www.budgiecollective.com)

Comment: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/budgiecollective.com looks good regarding propagation.

Comment: It will take even longer, but you could always remove DNS from their servers. Find out what all your records are, or get them to enable zone transfers, and then move to someone like www.dnsmadeeasy.com. Update your nameserver records at your registrar. It will take time, but might be worth while and makes changing hosts (which I hope you will do) just that little bit easier later on.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I did a trace route and the DNS seemed to correctly resolve to the IP they said I was on. In fact, that's half the reason I think it's with them (and not DNS propagation). When I try to access Cpanel from the IP direct I get the same intermittent behavior.

Comment: If it's intermittent on the IP that pretty conclusively discredits the DNS theory.

Comment: @MarkHenderson that's what I was afraid of.  But yes it might be the crucial first step. It's the last straw in a string of issues. Is there anything though in the mean time I can do to get my site up? What could they have done wrong?

Comment: I had Cloudflare handling my DNS, but I asked my host to re-route to their own name servers to simplify the troubleshooting. This was very early on so I'm not anticipating this would impact the system. But now I'm looking for anything.

Comment: @ceejayoz selecting anything other than A on whatsmydns.net produces a lot of errors. (e.g. PTR results in "Error: Invalid IP address")